# Can't connect to the site using Selenium using a proxy Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Can't connect to the site using Selenium using a proxy Java, proxy server is active but it doesent working with my programm.

My code:

```
public void start(){

        String proxyAddress = "130.185.126.159";
        int proxyPort = 6774;
        String proxyUsername = "lznbghpe";
        String proxyPassword = "16z9hv6q9fhu";

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

        String proxyAuth = proxyUsername + ":" + proxyPassword;
        proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setProxy(proxy);
        options.addArguments("--headless"); // Run in headless mode
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://mycgsportal.com/MyCGS/CGSAccount/Login");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

}
```

Response:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. But for me, I want Selenium to use the HTTP proxy configured in my OS. Maybe that is something for you, too.
I was able to do that via `ProxyType.AUTODETECT`

```
// Create a Proxy object and let it use the OS proxy settings
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.AUTODETECT);

// Create ChromeOptions instance and set the proxy options
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setProxy(proxy);
```

Tests with selenium-java 4.18.0